# Install zabbix on multiple hosts

Tags: linux, ssh, monitoring, openssh, zabbix

Is it possible to install Zabbix agent on multiple host, say 500, using a single ssh script and a .dat file listing all host names?

```
     <hosts.dat>

                  hostnames  IP
                  abchost    10.21.x.x
                  abshost    10.21.x.x
                  asdhost    12.23.x.x
                  .
                  .
                  .
                  so on.
```

Comment: Yes, this is possible.

Comment: The .dat file contains a mixed list of hosts, running on Linux and windows platforms. I need to check the platforms, kernel versions and then install Zabbix Agent on them. I have been using putty for ssh. I am also open to using OpenSSH. How can i write a script to accommodate all this?